# Неправильное отображение Radiobutton в приложении

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Столкнулся с неправильным отображением на экране RadioButton'ов. По задумке они должны отображаться, нормально (кружочек и справа текст), а они отображаются, как простой текст, да еще и не работают (не кликабельны) XML RadioGroup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
tools:context=".ui.AddDate">

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.CalendarView"
    android:layout_width="345dp"
    android:layout_height="314dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="264dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:showWeekNumber="true"
    android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="#FF5722"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Инфо об улье:"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Цвет матки:"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.167"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:text="Порода матки:"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.177"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Введите текст"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="242dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:background="#FFEB3B"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:text="Сохранить"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Введите текст"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Выберите дату закладки маток"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Белый"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_yellow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Желтый"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Красный"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Зеленый"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Синий"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Activity:

```
 RadioGroup rg = findViewById(R.id.rg);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case -1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ничего не выбрано",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_white:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Белый",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_yellow:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Желтый",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_blue:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Синий",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_red:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Красный",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.rb_green:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Зеленый",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Никаких ошибок, вылетов нет при отладке, при нажатии на RadioButton'ы никакой реакции. Отображение на экране такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как их сделать нормальными и работающими? Спасибо большое!

Comment: Попробуйте ширины всем вьюхам (RadioGroup и RadioButton) сделать match_parent, высоту - wrap_content и убрать android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, попробовал, не помогло...

Comment: Должно работать... Может у вас в стилях что-то не то или вы перепутали, например, файлы разметки? Вы точно на эмуляторе/девайсе запускаете, а не в превью смотрите на итоговый результат?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в стилях я ничего не трогал) Код и разметка связаны верно, если Вы об этом, запускаю на мобильном телефоне. Так же была проблема с объектом Spinner, несмотря на верное заполнение он тоже отображался неверно (была только 1ая его строка, без возможности выбора других, просто текст первого варианта, никаких характерных для Spinner'a обозначений)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, изменил изображение того, как отображаются кнопки, на устройстве абсолютно так же

Comment: А покажите всю разметку - возможно вы явно в ней выше где-то запретили клики/тачи например.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил в тему

Comment: попробуйте убрать android:textAlignment

Comment: @Style-7, убрал, не помогло

Comment: В приведенном коде проблем нет, если его скопировать в отдельный проект. Скорей всего что-то со стилями. Покажите, как вы кастомизируете radio button и какая у вас базовая тема?

Comment: @Vadik, подскажите, пожалуйста, что скинуть, не так давно в Андроиде, еще не сильно понимаю в этом) Спасибо

Comment: @StudyAndroid стили у вас, скорее всего в `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил файл styles.xml (он тут весь полностью)

Comment: В стилях ничего криминального тоже не видно... Попробуйте вот эти строки из разметки удалить: `android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Удалил, ничего не поменялось... Может еще что-то скинуть?

Comment: Других идей нет - должно и так работать, там сложно что-то сломать по идее... Попробуйте, например, вот этот проект у себя запустить - если там работает - посмотрите чем оно от вашего отличается: https://github.com/NoorMohammedAnik/RadioButton

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я посмотрел, вроде ничего не заметил. У меня есть предположение, что дело в gradle или каких-то библиотеках, может быть такое? Когда я открыл Ваш проект, Android Studio стал подгружать gradle и еще какие-то библиотеки

Comment: Т.е. вы его запустили (этот проект по ссылке) и там всё работает? По идее дело не должно быть в библиотеках. Попробуйте код из проекта по ссылке скопировать в свой проект, например в отдельной активити - будет ли работать в вашем проекте?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, Ваш проект отлично работает. Пробовал копировать в свой проект, проблема сохранилась. Проект я создал довольно давно, около года назад примерно, еще и на другом компьютере. Может ли быть в этом проблема?

Comment: В теории может быть... Попробуйте build->clean сделать и/или InvalidateCahce&Restart. Плюс удалить все build папки (2 штуки должно быть) и папку `.gradle` а потом SyncProjectWithGradleFiles сделать. Если и это не поможет... Ну, наверное можно попробовать в студии новый проект создать и в него просто копи-пастом весь код перенести - авось поможет)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127107/discussion-on-question-by-studyandroid---radiobutton--).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, похоже, что проблема была где-то в ресурсах, пересоздать проект помогло, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в файлах проекта, проблема решилась путем пересоздания проекта.